# how to break a while loop immediately

Tags: python, while-loop, pyqt5, nested-loops, pyserial

I have this Class `ScaleWorker`

which is a worker running in a thread in the main interface

it contains `receave_scaledata` which waits for receaving data from a device and forward it to the 
interface

the function runs in a while loop
with the condition `while my_serial.is_open and self.continue_run:`

with the function

```
def stop_me(self):
        self.continue_run = False
```

the function can be stopped when a signal is send from the main interface to execute `stop_me`

`self.continue_run = True` is switched to `True` and the loop breaks

at the end it emits `self.finishedworking.emit()`
which tell the thread in the main interface to quit

`self.scaleworker.finishedworking.connect(self.thread.quit)`

The Problem is that the function `receave_scaledata` contains a function from `pyserial`

`data_left = my_serial.inWaiting()`

this function waits forever till it receaves data

 without incoming data the other code gets not executed 
so when a signal is send to quit the thread the signal is stuck till data comes into the device and then the loop breaks

Im looking for a way to tell the worker to emit `finishedworking` right away without getting blocked 
So far I could not find a way around it

the code is a little bit hard to execute withpout the device but maybe you can help me

here is the Code

```
import sys
import time

import re
import serial
from serial.tools import list_ports

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc



class ScaleWorker(qtc.QObject):

    work_signal = qtc.pyqtSignal(float)
    finishedworking = qtc.pyqtSignal()  # emmits that its finished

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.continue_run = False

    @qtc.pyqtSlot()
    def receave_scaledata(self):
        try:
            my_serial = serial.Serial(
                port="COM 3",
                baudrate=2400,
                bytesize=7,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                timeout=None,
                stopbits=1,)

            if my_serial.is_open:
                print("serial open")

                while my_serial.is_open and self.continue_run:
                    data = my_serial.read()  # wait forever till data arives
                    time.sleep(1)  # hard delay to receave all bites
                    data_left = my_serial.inWaiting()  # wait forever
                    data += my_serial.read(data_left) # pack all receaved bites into on variable
                    self.work_signal.emit(data)
                self.finishedworking.emit()

        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            print("not open")

    def stop_me(self):
        self.continue_run = False
```

Comment: Don't do IO on the main thread. Use a second thread that waits on the serial port and shares any data with the main thread when it becomes available.

Comment: then the problem gets transfered to the second thread

Comment: Yes, but your main thread can end the child thread at any time.

Comment: When you look at it closely, your question is not really *"how to break a while loop immediately"*, but *"how to cancel an ongoing read from a serial port"* - the loop has nothing to do with it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I simple yet robust way is to configure a rather short read timeout (~1 second) on the Serial port. You will just have to test whether `len(data) == 0` and do not process further the (non) incoming data.

That way you can be sure to be able to test for the stop request at least on each occurence of the timeout.